# Trouble merging 3 programs into one for a Arduino robot project

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I am currently building a robot that has 3 functions and so far have 3 different programs for the 3 functions:

1. Program one allows the robot to detect a black line on a light surface and follow it.
2. Program 2 allows a user to press a button on an IR remote and the robot will then rotate a servo that moves the arms
3. Program 3 allows the user to press another button to play an audio file

NOTE: ALL THESE PROGRAMS WORK FINE AND TESTED FINE INDIVIDUALLY

I merged program 1 and 2 together no problem and tested it on the robot and it functioned correctly. When I merge the 3rd program I get an error: 'rotateMotor' is not in this scope. It seems to me it most certainly is within scope. from when I looked at it. After some troubleshooting I did find removing the line const unsigned char voice1[] PROGMEM = {audio file here} and #include <PCM.h> makes the program function fine again. Can anyone help at all kind of at a wall here.

```
#include <IRremote.h> //include IR remote library
#include <Servo.h>
#include <PCM.h>

const unsigned char voice1[] PROGMEM = {
  audio file here
  };
  
#define IR_SENSOR_RIGHT 11
#define IR_SENSOR_LEFT 12
#define MOTOR_SPEED 165

int IRpin = 11;  // pin for the IR sensor
uint32_t Previous;
IRrecv irrecv(IRpin); //IR sensor gets IR pin input to arduino
decode_results results; //results of IR remote button press
Servo armservo; //create servo objects

//Right motor
int enableRightMotor = 6;
int rightMotorPin1 = 7;
int rightMotorPin2 = 8;

//Left motor
int enableLeftMotor = 5;
int leftMotorPin1 = 9;
int leftMotorPin2 = 10;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //begin IR function
 irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start receiver
 armservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo to pin on arduino
 pinMode (12,OUTPUT);
 TCCR0B = TCCR0B & B11111000 | B00000011 ;
  
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(enableRightMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightMotorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightMotorPin2, OUTPUT);
  
  pinMode(enableLeftMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftMotorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftMotorPin2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(IR_SENSOR_RIGHT, INPUT);
  pinMode(IR_SENSOR_LEFT, INPUT);
  rotateMotor(0,0);   
}


void loop()
{

  int rightIRSensorValue = digitalRead(IR_SENSOR_RIGHT);
  int leftIRSensorValue = digitalRead(IR_SENSOR_LEFT);

  //If none of the sensors detects black line, then go straight
  if (rightIRSensorValue == LOW && leftIRSensorValue == LOW)
  {
    rotateMotor(MOTOR_SPEED, MOTOR_SPEED);
  }
  
  //If right sensor detects black line, then turn right
  else if (rightIRSensorValue == HIGH && leftIRSensorValue == LOW )
  {
      rotateMotor(-MOTOR_SPEED, MOTOR_SPEED); 
  }
  
  //If left sensor detects black line, then turn left  
  else if (rightIRSensorValue == LOW && leftIRSensorValue == HIGH )
  {
      rotateMotor(MOTOR_SPEED, -MOTOR_SPEED); 
  } 
  
  //If both the sensors detect black line, then stop 
  else 
  {
    rotateMotor(0, 0);
  }

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) //if statement recieving result of button press
   {
     irrecv.resume();   // Receive next value
   }
   
  if (results.value == 16736925)  // if recieve button press 2 function will initialize code specific to my controller change via decoder program
    {
      armservo.write(0); //input 0 position on servo
      delay(1500); //delay next function 1.5 secs

      armservo.write(75); //input 75 degree position on servo
      delay(1500);

      armservo.write(0);
      delay(1500);

      armservo.write(90); //input 90 degree position on servo
      delay(1500);
    } 
}

void rotateMotor(int rightMotorSpeed, int leftMotorSpeed)
{
  if (rightMotorSpeed < 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(rightMotorPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorPin2,HIGH);    
  }
  
  else if (rightMotorSpeed > 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(rightMotorPin1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorPin2,LOW);      
  }
  
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(rightMotorPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorPin2,LOW);      
  }

  if (leftMotorSpeed < 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorPin2,HIGH);    
  }
  
  else if (leftMotorSpeed > 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorPin1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorPin2,LOW);      
  }
  
  else 
  {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorPin2,LOW);      
  }
  
  analogWrite(enableRightMotor, abs(rightMotorSpeed));
  analogWrite(enableLeftMotor, abs(leftMotorSpeed));    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Put a *forward declaration* of `rotateMotor` before the function where `rotateMotor` is first used. That would be above the `setup` function which calls `rotateMotor(0,0);`. If no matching declaration of `rotateMotor` has been seen by the compiler when it reaches that line, it will fail. The forward declaration should look exacly like in the definition of the function:

  ```cpp
  // only a declaration, no definition:
  void rotateMotor(int rightMotorSpeed, int leftMotorSpeed);
  ```

or

- Move the whole definition of `rotateMotor` before the `setup` function.

Comment: I did what you said and it did work however now I am getting a different error saying: Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

Comment: @mtom Ok, if you can't figure out what the problem is, open a new question and include the full error message as well as a [mre].